# error MSB3094: "DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 428 item(s)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am typing in a cmd:

```
dotnet publish MyProject.Web.csproj --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.1 --runtime win-x64 --self-contained true --output '\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish'
```

And I am getting the following error.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(152,5): error MSB3094: "DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 428 item(s). They must have the same number of items. [C:\BuildAgent\work\7e7906b985af1c3\src\MyProject.Web\MyProject.Web.csproj]
```

Here is my MyProject.Web.csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Authors>MyCompany Ltd</Authors>
    <Company>MyCompany Ltd</Company>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0</FileVersion>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="5.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.EntityFramework\MyProject.EntityFramework.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have seen similar solutions to stackoverflow but they are all for Visual Studio. I am running the command from a cmd directly.
Anyone knows what is causing that?

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/543#issuecomment-271656546